# How can I make sure that my Selector does not overlap my text-area box when hover ? I would like for the selector to smoothly push down the text-area

Tags: forms, input, selector, overlap

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaWfd.jpg)
The selector overlaps the text-area

I would like for the selector to push down the text-area box smoothly when it is hovered over. The Selector just over laps the text area which is what I don't want I would love for the selector to act as a block and smoothly push down the elements below it.

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, as well as any debugging observations you have made.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.